# Minimal dependencies for Cleanup code command line tool

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup, command-line-tool

We are using ReSharper command-line tool (clean up code) for our development.
We have a requirement to clean up our c# files.
So, we are using the ReSharper command line tool (https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/#section=commandline), and it works fine with the sample project.

Our requirement is "Format the file and Add regions" to all .cs files.
This tool contains more .exe and dlls, but we need minimal dependencies for our work (Just to clean up the code and add regions).

FYI: We moved the **Cleanupcode.exe** to separate folder but it doesn't run.

We just want to move the required .exe and dll's to separate folder for running 'Cleanupcode.exe'.

Please suggest what are the minimal dependencies to run the 'Cleanupcode.exe'?

Comment: Where is the executable located (Cleanupcode.exe)?  You may need full path to file or put file in project folder.  Do you get any errors?

Comment: @jdweng We didn't get any errors, we just want to move the required .exe and dll's to separate folder for running 'Cleanupcode.exe' because the project size is kinda big (389mb).

Comment: The you need to add the relative path of where you located files so c# executable can find the file.

Comment: @jdweng We moved out the Cleanupcode.exe from the main folder where all the dll's and other .exe are presented.
Given Path:  PS 'C:\Temp> .\cleanupcode.exe C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Resharper\ReSharper ReSharper.sln'.
Cleanupcode.exe is presented in the Temp folder.

It throws error:
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'JetBrains.ReSharperAutomationTools.CommandLine.Common, Version=777.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @jdweng actually we moved the 'Cleanupcode.exe' alone from Resharper project folder to Temp folder ('C:\Temp), for running the Cleanupcode.exe we need dependent dll's right so, we want to know the required dll's to run the Cleanupcode.exe.

If we keep the Cleanupcode.exe in the Resharper project folder, it works fine but we don't want the entire project folder.

Comment: You could modify the PAT environmental variable to located main executables but you still need to put the any dlls it uses in same folder.

Comment: What you're doing does not make sense. Cleanupcode.exe is just the runner, it uses most of the assemblies located in the command-line tools folder. Why do you need to split up command-line tools?